# Assigning each user a variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In one of my project, I want to assign each incoming user to the node server a copy of a variable `num`. I have below code in which I have a global `num` variable.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var cors=require('cors');
var path=require('path');
app.use(cors());
var num;
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    num=0;
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/count.html'));
});
app.get('/increase',(req,res)=>{
    num=num+1;
    res.json({"num":num});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

What I am trying to achieve is that each user coming on the server should have their own num variable which is exclusively their own. When they hit `increase` route, their own copy of `num` should increase. But what is happening instead is that since num is global variable, any change in `num` is reflected to all of the user's `num`. In other words, I would like to store request level data.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

In order to separate users in that way you would have to implement sessions. Take a look at the express-session package on NPM. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Once you have the session ID included in the request you could create an object to store the "nums" in memory:

```
const nums = {};

app.get('/increase',(req,res)=>{
    if(nums[req.session.id]){
       nums[req.session.id]++;
    }
    else {nums[req.session.id] = 1} 
    res.json({"num":nums[req.session.id]});
});
```

Comment: Thanxx for the answer, but is there any other way that doesn't uses sessions?

Comment: You could use something like req.ip but it gets complicated pretty quickly if you put any proxies infront of it. just replace the req.session.id with req.ip, also hard to test because you're always on the same IP locally :')

Comment: Instead of sessions you should use arbitrary unique identifiers assigned to each user (i.e: uuid). This way, a user returning with another session doesn't lose/reset their `num`. Obviously, the `/increase` has to receive the unique identifier as a param.